# The performance cost to using ref instead of returning same types?

Tags: c#, performance, ref

Hi this is something that's really bothering me and I'm hoping someone has an answer for me. I've been reading about `ref` (and `out`) and I'm trying to figure out if I'm slowing down my code using `ref`s. Commonly I will replace something like:

```
int AddToInt(int original, int add){ return original+add; }
```

with

```
void AddToInt(ref int original, int add){ original+=add; } // 1st parameter gets the result
```

because to my eyes this

```
AddToInt(ref _value, _add);
```

is easier to read AND code than this

```
_value = AddToInt(_value, _add);
```

I know precisely what I'm doing on the code using `ref`, as opposed to returning  a value. However, performance is something I take seriously, and apparently dereferencing and cleanup is a lot slower when you use refs.

What I'd like to know is *why* every post I read says there is very few places you would typically pass a `ref` (I know the examples are contrived, but I hope you get the idea), when it seems to me that the `ref` example is smaller, cleaner and more exact.

I'd also love to know why `ref` really is slower than returning a value type - to me it would seem to me, if I was going to edit the function value a lot before returning it, that it would be quicker to reference the actual variable to edit it as opposed to an instance of that variable shortly before it gets cleaned from memory.

Comment: I'd usually prefer returning a value for stylistic reasons, since I like side effect free functions.

Comment: You are trying to figure out the performance cost? Ask a profiler, don't ask us!

Comment: The first case is easier to read because you have named your method accordingly. Something like `_value = Add(_value, _add);` or `_value = SumOf(_value, _add);` is more readable for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# 'ref' keyword, performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900903/c-sharp-ref-keyword-performance)

Comment: [Results of my small benchmark](http://slides.com/timurseitosmanov/to-pure-or-not-to-pure#/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main time that "ref" is used in the same sentence as performance is when discussing some very atypical cases, for example in XNA scenarios where the game "objects" are quite commonly represented by structs rather than classes to avoid problems with GC (which has a disproportionate impact on XNA). This becomes useful to:

- prevent copying an oversized struct multiple times on the stack
- prevent data loss due to mutating a struct copy (XNA structs are commonly mutable, against normal practice)
- allow passing a struct in an an array **directly**, rather than ever copying it out and back in

In all other cases, "ref" is more commonly associated with an additional side-effect, not easily expressed in the return value (for example see `Monitor.TryEnter`).

If you don't have a scenario like the XNA/struct one, and there is no awkward side effect, then just use the return value. In addition to being more typical (which in itself has value), it could well involve passing less data (and int is smaller than a ref on x64 for example), and could require less dereferencing.

Finally, the return approach is more versatile; you don't always want to update the source. Contrast:

```
// want to accumulate, no ref
x = Add(x, 5);

// want to accumulate, ref
Add(ref x, 5);

// no accumulate, no ref
y = Add(x, 5);

// no accumulate, ref
y = x;
Add(ref y, x);
```

I think the last is the least clear (with the other "ref" one close behind it) and ref usage is **even less clear** in languages where it is not explicit (VB for example).

Comment: Thanks, that explains precisely where I do and don't want to use ref and why! Best of all you've given me a bunch of things to check out I wouldn't have otherwise.

Comment: One important advantage of ref, though, referencing your example: if something is passed by reference to a method like Add, it may be possible for the method to perform the update in lock-free, non-blocking, atomic, thread-safe fashion.  So if two threads simultaneously call an "Add" method as shown in the second example, x would have ten added to it.  By contrast, if one or both threads did the update as shown in the first example, one thread might undo the update performed by the other.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: The "Add" method could do so internally.  Of course, doing so would only be of value if all the code which manipulated the thing requiring such care used Interlocked methods, but if the thing in question is a custom data type, that is a realistic possibility.

Answer (score 7):

The main purpose of using the ref keyword is to signify that the variable's value can be changed by the function its being passed into. When you pass a variable by value, updates from within the function don't effect the original copy.

Its extremely useful (and faster) for situations when you want multiple return values and building a special struct or class for the return values would be overkill. For example,

```
public void Quaternion.GetRollPitchYaw(ref double roll, ref double pitch, ref double yaw){
    roll = something;
    pitch = something;
    yaw = something;
}
```

This is a pretty fundamental pattern in languages that have unrestricted use of pointers. In c/c++ you frequently see primitives being passed around by value with classes and arrays as pointers. C# does just the opposite so 'ref' is handy in situations like the above.

When you pass a variable you want updated into a function by ref, only 1 write operation is necessary to give you your result. When returning values however, you normally write to some variable inside the function, return it, then write it again to the destination variable. Depending on the data, this could add unnecessary overhead. Anyhow, these are the main things that I typically consider before using the ref keyword.

Sometimes ref is a little faster when used like this in c# but not enough to use it as a goto justification for performance.

Here's what I got on a 7 year old machine using the code below passing and updating a 100k string by ref and by value.

Output:

iterations: 10000000 
byref: 165ms 
byval: 417ms

```
private void m_btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    string s = "";
    string value = new string ('x', 100000);    // 100k string
    int iterations = 10000000;

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Update by ref
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    sw.Start();
    for (var n = 0; n < iterations; n++) {
        SetStringValue(ref s, ref value);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    long proc1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    sw.Reset();

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Update by value
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    sw.Start();
    for (var n = 0; n < iterations; n++) {
        s = SetStringValue(s, value);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    long proc2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    Console.WriteLine("iterations: {0} \nbyref: {1}ms \nbyval: {2}ms", iterations, proc1, proc2);
}

public string SetStringValue(string input, string value) {
    input = value;
    return input;
}

public void SetStringValue(ref string input, ref string value) {
    input = value;
}
```

Comment: At that size for an object, creating a new copy is going to be more expensive of course. For most normal cases I dont think there can be that big difference.

Comment: all throw the results are correct, the actions are not the same on the two functions. Actually the one function is return something, the other not. The ref keyword alone compare with the non ref keyword is not faster but almost the same, if not slower. To make a correct measure make two functions with the same actions and only the `ref` must change...

Answer (score 5):

I have to agree with Ondrej here. From a stylistic view, if you start passing everything with `ref` you will eventually end up working with devs who will want to strangle you for designing an API like this!

Just return stuff from the method, don't have 100% of your methods returning `void`. What you are doing will lead to very unclean code and might confuse other devs who end up working on your code. Favour clarity over performance here, since you won't gain much in optomization anyway.

check this SO post: [C# 'ref' keyword, performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900903/c-sharp-ref-keyword-performance)

and this article from Jon Skeet: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

Using ref for basic datatypes is not a good idea.
Especially for simple methods which have few lines of code.
First off C# compiler will do lots of optimizations to make the code faster.
As per my benchmark https://rextester.com/CQJR12339 passing by ref has degraded the performance.
When a reference is passed , you are copying 8bytes as a pointer variable (assuming 64 bit processor)  why not pass a 8Bytes double directly?

Pass by ref is useful in case of larger objects , For example a string which has lots of characters.

Answer (score 0):

First, **don't** bother whether using `ref` is slower or faster. It's premature optimization. In 99.9999% cases you won't run into a situation this would cause a performance bottleneck.

Second, returning the result of the calculation as a return value as opposed to using `ref` is preferred because of the usual 'functional' nature of C-like languages. It leads to better chaining of statements/calls.

Update: Adding evidence from an actual performance benchmark, which shows the difference is ~1%, and hence readability over premature optimization is the suggested approach. Plus, `ref` turns out to be actually *slower* than a return value; however, as the difference is so small, repeated runs of the benchmark may end up opposite.

Results for .NET 6.0.7:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AddToIntBase | 375.6 us | 5.36 us | 4.18 us |
| AddToIntReturn | 378.6 us | 7.22 us | 7.41 us |
| AddToIntReturnInline | 375.5 us | 4.84 us | 4.04 us |
| AddToIntRef | 383.7 us | 5.92 us | 5.25 us |
| AddToIntRefInline | 384.2 us | 7.29 us | 8.96 us |

Results for .NET 4.8 *(because this is an 11-year-old question)* are essentially the same:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AddToIntBase | 381.3 us | 7.40 us | 7.92 us |
| AddToIntReturn | 380.8 us | 7.00 us | 6.55 us |
| AddToIntReturnInline | 380.0 us | 5.03 us | 4.20 us |
| AddToIntRef | 378.5 us | 6.62 us | 5.87 us |
| AddToIntRefInline | 381.5 us | 4.50 us | 3.76 us |

Benchmark code:

```
public class AddToIntBenchmark
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void AddToIntBase()
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) result += i;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void AddToIntReturn()
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) result = AddToInt(result, i);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void AddToIntReturnInline()
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) result = AddToIntInline(result, i);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void AddToIntRef()
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) AddToInt(ref result, i);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void AddToIntRefInline()
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) AddToIntInline(ref result, i);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private int AddToIntInline(int original, int add) { return original + add; }

    private int AddToInt(int original, int add) { return original + add; }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private void AddToIntInline(ref int original, int add) { original += add; }

    private void AddToInt(ref int original, int add) { original += add; }
}
```

Environment: .NET 6.0.7, Intel Xeon Gold 16-core 2.4 GHz, WS2019 virtual machine

Comment: I always interpret these "It's premature optimization" answers as "I don't know".

Comment: Well actually I *do know* and know how to measure it. However, it makes no sense at all to waste time because we are talking about a few CPU cycles' difference per call.

Comment: I don't like (working with) devs that always use performance as the main case when choosing between some coding styles/designs/architectures in NON performance critical sectors. Happens a lot.

Comment: Yeah. great. I come here looking for that info because I deal with high perforamnce trading applications. There ARE cases you look to move to structs to take load off the gc...

Comment: I think it's good to know performance implications. For example boxing/unboxing is affecting performance and should be avoided. No profiler will show boxing as a performance problem, but still could degrade performance if overused. Good to know when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

in your case, using ref is a bad idea.
when using ref, the program will read a pointer off of the stack, than read the value the pointer is pointing at.
but if you were to pass by value it would only need to read the value off of the stack, basically reducing the amount of reads by half.

passing by reference should only be used for medium to large data structures like, for example, 3D models or arrays.