# Why not use "in" for method parameters whenever possible?

Tags: c#

In C# we can specify `in` on struct method parameters so that they are passed as readonly references:

```
public int TimesTwo(in int number)
{
    return number * 2;
}
```

This is almost the same as using `ref` but does not allow modifications to the parameter:

```
public int TimesTwo(in int number)
{
    number *= 2; // Compiler error
    return number;
}
```

Additionally it does not require specifying the keyword when calling, like `ref` does:

```
var x = 1;
var y = TimesTwo(x);
var z = TimesTwo(in x);
// y and z are both 2
```

In some scenarios this is not possible, like when you need to modify the parameter or with async or iterator methods which do not allow `in`. But the question is, in 99% of cases where the parameter is only read then **why not specify `in`**?

When `in` is **not** specified, the parameter passed is copied to a local variable. This copying can take time that can be noticeable for large structs in tight loops, as [Microsoft says here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier#overload-resolution-rules).

With `in`, the reference is passed, so no copying takes place. Maybe the time saved not copying is negligible in most cases, but I want to know if there is any reason other than the standard "it clutters the code" or "it's a micro-optimization you shouldn't be worrying about".

As far as I can tell this "micro-optimization" of bypassing struct copying is exactly why `in` was introduced. Are there other reasons why this would be bad practice to just throw it in everywhere for performance critical code?

Comment: _"In C# we can specify in on struct method parameters so that they are passed as readonly references"_ Note that this is only possible in C# 7.2

Comment: For these kinds of questions, I find https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ helpful. Also, some of it is thinking about how things are worded. Microsoft's choice of wording `Some struct type arguments may be large in size, and when methods are called in tight loops or critical code paths, the cost of copying those structures is critical.` Note they _explicitly_ mentioned `large` - so I'd be asking myself 'why did they use that?' Is there something different between large and small structs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does passing values by reference improve speed significantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501939/does-passing-values-by-reference-improve-speed-significantly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is also good for tight coupling. For example the following method from MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier):

```
static void Method(in int argument)
{
    // implementation removed
}

Method(5); // ok
Method(5L); // CS1503: no implicit conversion from long to int
```

Here's an interesting link for optimization (I copied their results)
which discusses about `readonly struct`, `readonly ref` and `in`:
https://faithlife.codes/blog/2017/12/in-will-make-your-code-slower/

```
Method                  Mean
PointByValue            25.09 ns
PointByRef              21.77 ns
PointByIn               34.59 ns  // our guy
ReadOnlyPointByValue    25.29 ns
ReadOnlyPointByRef      21.78 ns
ReadOnlyPointByIn       21.79 ns
```

Some further reading (Credit: Jon Skeet):

**MICRO-OPTIMIZATION: THE SURPRISING INEFFICIENCY OF READONLY FIELDS**

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/07/16/micro-optimization-the-surprising-inefficiency-of-readonly-fields/

Comment: That was an interesting read, and definitely a problem I wasn't considering! Particularly "Calling an instance method on a `readonly` struct makes a copy".

It seems from their conclusion and the test results, there is decent optimization in using `in` vs `value` **if the struct is marked `readonly`**. But with a struct not marked `readonly`, even if it is semantically readonly, there may be an even more noticeable performance penalty when calling instance methods.

Comment: It seems the benchmark linked in this answer was done with a C# language version where the necessary optimization for structs passed by `in` is turned off. Take a look at my [discovery](https://github.com/bgrainger/InPerformance/issues/2).

Comment: By empirical tests, the `in` parameter optimization is turned on by setting the project `LangVersion` at least to [8.0](https://github.com/bgrainger/InPerformance/issues/2#issuecomment-1545961441).