# Why is it not necessary to indicate ByVal/ByRef anymore?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, byref, byval

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 Service pack (proposed on Windows Update), and I can see a new feature on the "intellisense" that means when I write a `Function` or `Sub` in VB.NET it doesn't auto-complete parameters with `ByRef` or `ByVal`...

1) Is there anyway that I can configure this option back to how it was before?

2) If I don't specify `ByX`, which one is used by default? (it seems like it is always `ByRef`)

Comment: The default is `ByVal`, but be sure you understand what [passing by value and by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx) actually means.

Comment: You almost always want to pass `ByVal`, and this is in fact the default. There's no reason for the code to be cluttered up with `ByVal` all over the place; that's just "noise". Only specify `ByRef` explicitly when you absolutely must have pass-by-reference semantics.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tim covered what you asked directly, but something else to keep in mind is that any reference type variable, like a user defined class even if passed by value will allow you to make changes to that instances properties etc that stay.  It won't however allow you to change the entire object.  Which may be why it seemed to you to be defaulting to by reference

```
Public Sub (Something As WhateverClass) 
  Something = New WhateverClass 'will result in no changes when outside this method

  Something.Property1 = "Test"  'will result in an updated property when outside this method
End Sub
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eek064h4.aspx):

> The value of a reference type is a pointer to the data elsewhere in memory.
>     This means that when you pass a reference type by value,
>   the procedure code has a pointer to the underlying element's data, 
>   even though it cannot access the underlying element itself. For
>   example,  if the element is an array variable, the procedure code does
>   not have access to the variable itself, but it can access the array
>   members.

Comment: This answer is kinda of misleading since it explains "how the value of a reference type works" whereas the question is "why is it not necessary to indicate ByVal/ByRef anymore?"

Answer (score 44):

It seems that this post covers your question:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/carlosq/archive/2011/03/15/vs-2010-sp1-changing-quot-byval-quot-vb-net-code-editor-experience.aspx

So no,  there is no way to get the old behaviour. From now on `ByVal` is the default (what it was before) and it won't get added automatically to the method parameters.

In my opinion this is a good decision since it's making VB.NET a bit more consistent with C# and avoids unnecessary "noises"(it's already verbose enough).

Old behaviour:

```
Private Sub test(ByVal test As String)
End Sub
```

New behaviour

```
Private Sub test(test As String)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 16):

Beware when transferring routines to VBA, where the default is `ByRef` (see, e.g., "The Default Method Of Passing Parameters" at [the bottom of this page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx), by the great Chip Pearson).
That can be messy.

Comment: The same is true when transferring routines to VB6 where the default is also `ByRef`