# Difference between ByVal sender as object.... and Sender as object

Tags: vb.net, eventargs, byval

I'm completely new to coding, and have been trying do a lot of at home research. I'm currently using VB 2012 and have noticed that on a lot of forums people have 
`(ByVal Sender as Object,...` present when I load up a button or form, my code automatically comes up as `(Sender as object...`. My question is what is the difference between the two and how do they separately affect the program?
Me:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Handles Button1.Click
End Sub
```

Random:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    'Handles Button1.Click
    sayHello(sender)
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9207733/1287352

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.  `ByVal` is the default mechanism for passing parameters.  In older versions of VB.NET, the IDE would add `ByVal` by default.  In newer versions, `ByVal` is implicit unless you specify `ByRef` explicitly.

Comment: Ok. Thank you this left me feeling like something was missing in my settings.